# Dendrograms with SciPy

Tags: dataframe, scipy, time-series, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a dataset that I shaped according to my needs, the dataframe is as follows:

```
Index        A    B    C    D   ..... Z
Date/Time    1    0    0    0,35  ... 1
Date/Time    0,75 1    1    1         1
```

The total number of rows is 8878

What I try to do is create a time-series dendrogram (Example: Whole A column will be compared to whole B column in whole time).

I am expecting an output like this: [image: Example Dendrogram]
<sub>(source: [rsc.org](http://pubs.rsc.org/services/images/RSCpubs.ePlatform.Service.FreeContent.ImageService.svc/ImageService/Articleimage/2016/AY/c6ay01061j/c6ay01061j-f4_hi-res.gif))</sub>

I tried to construct the linkage matrix with `Z = hierarchy.linkage(X, 'ward')`

However, when I print the dendrogram, it just shows an empty picture.

There is no problem if a compare every time point with each other and plot, but in that way, the dendrogram becomes way too complicated to observe even in truncated form.

Is there a way to handle the data as a whole time series and compare within columns in SciPy?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).